# What's the simplest way to navigate through a list of images?

Tags: php, javascript, html

The purpose of this is to view remote images with a browser. I already have set apache and I can see the folder of pictures with directory listing. The bad thing, is that I have to click each image, each time I want to see one.

What I want is to navigate through the images in the folder using the arrows in my keyboard. I don't want any UI, just the image.

What's the best thing to do this? Is it possible to do using just HTML5?

Thanks.

Comment: By no UI I assume you mean you don't want any buttons or anything, just a image *presumably* centered on the screen? left and right arrows to scroll left and right?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I want. The image doesn't even need to be centered, just the way the browser shows it.

Comment: if you want a quick and simple solution look [here](http://galleria.aino.se/) - this requires jQuery... and by quick and simple I mean you have to write little code and setup is a breeze. Alternatively you can just preload all of the images into a element array and cycle through them when the user *keysdown* left or right

Comment: Isn't there something simpler? I mean, the html code must be like `<img src="IMG_4928.JPG"/>` but with the ability to seek the next photo. PHP may be?

Comment: you may as well use javascript... as you will already be using it for capturing the keyboard events you may as well use it to load the images.

Comment: I have added my answer. Very simple, few lines of JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple gallery with keyboard navigation. You can (in php) echo out the directory listing of images as a array in js.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/hSknE/12/)

[Full Screen Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/hSknE/12/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think of is [Single File PHP Gallery](http://sye.dk/sfpg/).  It's one file.  You add it to that directory and it makes it into a gallery.  I don't know if it supports the keyboard navigation you're looking for.

The most straightforward approach would really be javascript, as mentioned by rlemon.  PHP is overkill for what you've described and by itself cannot add the keyboard shortcuts.  You need javascript for that part.  The Single File PHP Gallery might work if you're trying to avoid writing any code, though.

Answer (score 0):

Or try [Files app](https://files.photo.gallery/), see [demo](https://files.photo.gallery/demo/).

> Files is a single-file PHP app that can be dropped into any directory
> on your server, instantly creating a gallery of files and folders. It
> supports all file types and allows you to preview images, video, audio
> and code.